# Having a network output as another network parameters

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, parameter-passing, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I have `y = Y(x;theta)` and `theta = M(t;omega)`, where `x` and `t` are input variables (given from the dataset), and `theta` and `omega` trainable parameters. I need to have `theta` as function of `omega`. Then, I have a loss function over `y` and need to backpropagate the gradient through `M` up to `Y`. How can I create such a structure in pytorch?

Currently, my network is built as follows (`sizes` is a list of integers, defined as `sizes = [input_size, hidden1_size, hidden2_size, ..., output_size]`)

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class M(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, sizes):
        super(Y, self).__init__()
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(0, len(sizes) - 1):
            self.layers.append(nn.Linear(sizes[i], sizes[i+1]))

    def forward(self, x):
        for l in self.layers[:-1]:
            x = F.relu(l(x))
        x = self.layers[-1](x)

        return x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is quite simple or I didn't get your query correctly.

`x`, `t` are your input variables.

Now let us define a network `M` that will take input t and output `theta`.

```
M = nn.Sequential(....) # declare network here
```

Next, we define a network `Y`. This here might be tricky as you want to use theta as parameters. It might be easier and intuitive to work with functional counterparts of the modules declared in `nn` (see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html). I will try to give an example of this assuming theta are params of a linear module.

```
class Y(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        # declare any modules here

    def forward(self, theta, x):
        return nn.functional.linear(input=x, weight=theta, bias=None)
```

The overall forward pass would be

```
def forward(t, x, M, Y):
    theta = M(t)
    output = Y(theta, x)
    return output
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am unfamiliar with using modules to define a network. Also, how would you modify your code for multiple layers? I guess I have to manually split `theta` according to the size of each layer, right?
I have edited my question to provide my implementation of `M`. It would be great if you could help me writing the `Y` in a similar way (with multiple layers). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Simon Can you explain how you want to use output of M i.e theta. Just writing mathematical operations would do.

Comment: `theta` just has to be assigned to `Y` parameters. 
Your `return nn.functional.linear(input=x, weight=theta, bias=None)` is fine if `theta` would be only the linear weights of the first layer of network `Y`, but I need to do it all layers, biases included. 
One way would be having `theta` as all weights and biases stacked, then loop over it (I need to save all sizes beforehand) as assign them as you have written. 
I don't really like this way, and I was wondering if there is a better one.

Comment: I am not able to imagine how would you not have to do that in any case. If your network M outputs a single vector, you will have to rearrange it to get parameters for Y in any case right?

Comment: Well yes, unless there are particular structures in pytorch that I am not aware of (my knowledge of pytorch is rather basic :D). 
Anyway, I'll start writing the loops using your code and se if anyone else replies. If not, I'll accept yours (your code helped me anyway). Thanks!

Comment: @Simon I am not aware of any structure/constructs in torch to support your use-case and this was the cleanest way I could think of. For declaring network M or simple models you can check `nn.Sequential` it is pretty useful and code looks clean